# the best way to postpone callback till event

Tags: javascript, callback, queue

What would you suggest in case we need to postpone a callback in some circumstances and call it later, when an event occurs?
There are currently several queuing modules but I have not found one, which meet requirements as this one. I mean one don't run tasks out of queue till they are done. You run them when there is a suitable parameter value or the callback. For example,

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="id1">
<input type="text" id="id2">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("id1")
        .addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                upper(e.target.value);
            }
        });

    document.getElementById("id2")
        .addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                delayed(e.target.value);
            }
        });

    function upper(x){
        if (parseInt(x) == x) {
            next_level(x, function(y){
                alert(y);
            });
        } else {
                alert('not int');
        }
    }

    function next_level(x, callback){
        y = Math.random() * 10;
        if (y < x){
            callback(y);
        } else {
            // postpone callback till y comes from id2 
            // put it into a queue
        }
    }

    function delayed(y){
        // take 1st element/callback from the queue
        // call it with y
        // if queue is empty, do nothing  
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain please what this means for you: " when there is a suitable parameter value"? What would be the other case. What is a "not-suitable" value? and how can you check the difference?

Comment: `if (y < x)` in this case we call the callback immediately, otherwise we're waiting for the event (the value will come from other source). Well, in the real case of course `y` isn't a random number, there is a sophisticated way to get it but for the demo taking a random y and comparing it to `x` should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

I've edited the code. This is more similar to your code example, but I'm still not sure I understand exactly what desired behavior is. Let me know if comments if this is wrong.

```js
document.getElementById("id1")
  .addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      upper(e.target.value);
    }
  });

document.getElementById("id2")
  .addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      delayed(e.target.value);
    }
  });

function upper(x){
  if (parseInt(x) == x) {
    next_level(x, function(y){
      console.log(y);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('not int');
  }
}

const queue = [];

function next_level(x, callback){
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  if (y < x){
    callback(y);
  } else {
    queue.push(callback);
    // postpone callback till y comes from id2 
    // put it into a queue
  }
}

function delayed(y){
  if (queue.length > 0) {
    const cb = queue.shift();
    cb(y);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="id1" />
<input type="text" id="id2" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but you've misunderstood the question. I need some kind of queuing to accumulate callbacks in case we aren't lucky to get it passed on the first run. There may be many unlucky cases (we didn't get the number we expected) and we need to keep them all. Thereafter an event occurs, the number appeared from a different source, now we can call the first callback from the queue. As soon as we get another number, the next queue element get out.

Comment: Could you write a working example without the delay? I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking for still.

Comment: the example is given above. The issue is we're getting alerts only for `y < x`, while we should get alerts for any `x`. For `y >= x` they are just postponed till `id2` will get a value

Comment: I've edited my example. Let me know if this is more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my jsFiddle. It is similar to amcdrmtt's answer ut i tried to explain in the code what happen.

```
function next_level(x, callback){
  y = Math.random() * 10;
  if (y < x){
    callback(y);
  } else {
    // postpone callback till y comes from id2 
    // put it into a queue
    addToQueue(callback);
  }
}
// queue for callback methods
var queue = [];

// remember the callback for later
function addToQueue(func){
   queue.push(func); // add a method that calls func with the original arguments
    outputDiv.innerHTML += "<div>callback added to queue. queue length:" + queue.length + "</div>";
}
// call the last callback with a new value y
function delayed(y){
   // if queue is empty, do nothing
   if (queue.length === 0) {
    return;
   }
  // take 1st element/callback from the queue
  var firstCallback = queue.shift(); // also remove it from the queue
  // call it with y

  firstCallback(y);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7pfzvL0d/4/